# Is iron(III)nitrate changed and if so how?

Tags: equilibrium

We have the solution:

$\ce{Fe^3+(aq) + SCN-(aq) <=>Fe(SCN)^2+}$

When we add more $\ce {SCN-}$ to the solution above, the solution produces more product.

My question is, how does it affect $\ce {Fe^3+}$? Do the concentration of iron(III)nitrate change or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a stoichiometric amount of $\ce{SCN-}$ is added then the reaction is mostly

$$\ce{Fe^3+(aq) + SCN-(aq) <=>Fe(SCN)^2+(aq)}$$

If an excess of of $\ce{SCN-}$ is added then the reaction is mostly

$$\ce{Fe^3+(aq) + 2SCN-(aq) <=>[excess SCN-] Fe(SCN)2^+(aq)}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's Le Chatilers principle.If you increase the reactant,the product will also increase to maintain equilibrium.This has nothing to do with Fe ions as they are already in dynamic equilibrium,provided all the reactants are present in excess.

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvote?